# Does $\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\ln^2(x+1)}dx$ convergent?

Tags: improper-integrals

> Considering the convergence of intergral: $${\Large I=}\int_1^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\ln^2(x+1)}dx$$

Using Dirichlet theorem, we have the answer. Or $\displaystyle{0<\frac1x<\frac{1}{\ln^2(x+1)}}$, hence $I$ diverge.

But I think there will have a simplier answer. Please help.

Comment: It seems you already have a simplest answer.

Comment: I don't know what Dirichlet theorem you're talking about, but regardless, it's hard to imagine an answer simpler than $f(x)>1/x$.

Comment: Let $~x+1=e^t.$

Answer (score 0):

Another line of thoughts that leads to similar observations: The map $x \mapsto \frac{1}{\log^{2}(x+1)}: [1, +\infty[ \to \mathbb{R}$ is decreasing. Note that $k > \log^{2}(k+1)$ for large $k$; this implies
$$
\frac{1}{\log^{2}(k+1)} > \frac{1}{k}
$$
for large $k$; so by comparison test the series $\sum_{k} \frac{1}{\log^{2}(k+1)}$ diverges. By integral test we then see the divergence of the improper integral.